# Is there any way to iterate on two linkedlist at the same time

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I am trying find a way to loop through on multiple linkedlist but in this code it gives an error on `l2 = l2.next`

Is there any other way to find the longer linkedlist and loop through for both of them? I am not even sure if it is possible

[image]

```
const loopTwoList = function (l1, l2) {
    while(l1){
        const tmp1 = l1
        l1 = l1.next;
        tmp1.next =null;

        const tmp2 = l2
        l2 = l2.next;
        tmp2.next = null;
    }
};


loopTwoList([2,4,3],[5,6,4]);
```

I want to loop on these two list at the same time even if one of them is longer than the other one or equal.

So for the first loop I can use '2' and the '5' to do something and on the second loop I will have '4' and '6'. I am not sure if the while is going to help me to loop on both of them.

Comment: Seems `l1` is longer than `l2`. You *are* iterating both at the same time but the error indicates you reach the end of `l2` early. Just add more guards around it and don't consume the shorter list. Also account for the iteration in your `while` condition.

Comment: You need to tell us (or your code) what to do when the lists aren't the same length.  It's impossible from your snippet (which *is* nicely reduced to just the code needed to reproduce the problem) what the intent is.  eg it says "addTwoNumbers" which does not imply the use of a list (linked or otherwise) as that would likely be more than two.  Do you just want a sum of all of values in l1 + sum of all in l2?   Or only up to the shortest of the two?

Comment: It is not clear what you expect to happen. Please provide examples of input and expected output. There is `console.log`... what do you want to get as output there for your examples that currently fail?

Comment: @VLAZ Sorry for missing information. I tried to make it more clear by changing code and adding more information below code.

Comment: Your code with the edit works fine